# New homepage navigation breaks back button

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

On the new Stack Overflow start page, clicking on a question link, followed by pressing the “back” button in the browser, won’t return to the previously shown question list — instead it will show a new question list.

This is a shame, because I often click on a link and then notice that there’s another question that sounds interesting, too. So I go back and open that link as well. Except, I can no longer do this, since the question list is dynamically generated at every page load, rather than a static list (I’m assuming).

The same happens for when I (accidentally) close the question list tab and undo its closing in Chrome. I’m generally not sure why the list of shown questions is that unstable — I’m showing “recommended”, “recently active” questions on the “new” tab, the question list should be more stable than it is.

Comment: And when I was on the second of two pages, it would land me back on the first page, which is sub-optimal.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue to me. Not sure what Stack Overflow would be able to do about it. Note that this doesn't seem to happen in IE; it just redisplays the previously-loaded page. You have to refresh to get the up-to-date version. On the other hand, I _have_ noticed that the _search_ feature seems to reuse the current page; if I'm looking at the search results, hitting "Back" takes me two pages back. But that doesn't seem like what you're describing here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Indeed, it seems to be somewhat browser dependent. However, it used to work just fine in Chrome and now it doesn’t.

Comment: FWIW, I am/was using various versions of Firefox (sometimes an ESR version 31.8, sometimes the latest 39.0) on a Mac. I've not explored with Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Repo'ed on IE11. Another weird thing: today, when I clicked "back", there were several times where the "newest" page shown was for a while ago (I've seen the exact same page before). So sometimes it would have questions from several days ago saying "asked 5 minutes ago".

Comment: Repeatedly clicking on the “new” tab also refreshes the list in a non-obvious way: some items stay, while others are exchanged, without discernible pattern.

Comment: The new nav also breaks the `more hot questions` link (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300264/hot-network-questions-not-expanding-when-viewing-tags)

Comment: Is anything being done about this? I am still getting this problem and it is becoming very annoying. Can a dev give us an update on this please?

Comment: Reeeeeally wish we could bounty questions ... as this is still going on with no response from anyone.  Very annoying, and making me consider changing back to old navigation.

Comment: @Joe I’m pretty sure they’re actively working on it. (There was a tweet earlier today implying this but I forgot who tweeted it and I can’t find it now.)

Comment: Not a fix, but you can use the middle mouse button (on Windows/*nix) to open a link in a new tab. That, or enable "always open links in new tab".

Comment: @FuriousFolder I appreciate the helpful intention but I’m pretty certain that every single person in this thread already knows this.

Answer (score 13):

I'm experiencing similar issues with the <kbd>Back</kbd> button, when navigating back and forth around a tagged question list.

I can consistently recreate an issue, via the following steps in Chrome:

1. Click on one of my favorite tags: <kbd>[sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)</kbd>
2. This navigates to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server
3. I guess it takes in to account my preferred settings in the new nav and redirects to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/sql-server?show=all&sort=newest
4. This shows the following (accurate list):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

5. If I then click on the tag again at the top of the page: <kbd>[sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)</kbd>, it just reloads the same page as you'd expect.
6. If I then click the back button, I'd expect nothing to change, but it loads an older version of the tagged question list:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Notice the first question here is the last question on the previous list and everything is old: Views, Answered, Asked Time.

I've experienced the same when going into questions and back to the list via a tag.

Comment: So I'm not going crazy! Frustrating when you see *"asked 5 minutes ago"* but it's really 3 hours old

Answer (score 0):

Another related problem is that the top bar is duplicated (Chrome 39.0.2171.71 64-bit on Arch Linux 3.19.2-1):

[image: top bar duplicates]

Steps to reproduce (what I did to get the above image):

- Type e.g. `python` into the search bar.
- Click on the a question.
- Press the browser back button.

Goes away when:

- Page has been reloaded (F5).
- Another question is selected (only appears on the search results)

Comment: That seems to be an unrelated issue. I think it makes sense to report it separately.

Comment: I did, and I was told it was the same as this one?!?