# Hot network questions not expanding after changing tag filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, hot-questions

When I try and click on "more hot questions" once I've chosen a tag, it doesn't work. It just puts a `#` at the end of the URL and refreshes the page and my tags. Even without setting tags, it still won't expand as the page refreshes.

However, if I go to a question and click "more hot questions", it expands normally. So I've worked out it only happens when you're on the questions page.

Is this something that's on my end, or can others reproduce this bug?

Comment: Repo'ed on Chrome 44.  I didn't get a more hot questions on the main questions page, but going to Need Answers then I did get a more hot questions link, and that didn't work.

Comment: I get this on Firefox 39.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now: the code change I suggested below has been made, and I cannot reproduce the bug any more.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that *anything* that triggers an AJAX update of the question list (e.g. switching to a different tab, adding or removing filtered tags, changing the sort order, etc.) will trigger this bug.

If you open the browser error console (by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and selecting the Console tab), you will see the following error message appear on the console every time the question list is updated:

> TypeError: StackExchange.helpers.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions is not a function

The stack backtrace that comes with the message is not very helpful, since the code is minified, but it does mention "StackExchange.newnav.controllers.unifiedQuestionListController/<.onLoadSucceed" near the top of the call stack.

So, yes, this is definitely a bug.  I have not looked into the code in further detail, but hopefully this should at least be enough information for the SE devs to reproduce and fix this.

---

**Update:** This appears to be a simple typo in the `redrawPeripherals` function in `PartialJS\full-anon\23_NewNav.js`, as included in https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js.  The line that reads:

```js
StackExchange.helpers.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions();
```

should instead just read:

```js
StackExchange.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions();
```

I'll include a hotfix for this bug in the next version of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), if the SE devs don't get around to fixing it first.