# I see dead questions

Tags: bug, questions

So, this is probably something with the caching but tag pages recently started showing me deleted questions. For example:

[image]

Which in particular links to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199782/promises-wrapper

Which is deleted. This is on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/promise?show=all&sort=newest

This is new and I haven't seen the bug before.

Comment: Well, it wasn't asked yesterday.  This has been reported many times already, I think the prevailing conclusion is that you are looking at the page the way it was cached by your browser and associated with use of the back button.  [Check this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300233/new-homepage-navigation-breaks-back-button).

Comment: @HansPassant I was able to reproduce this in a new incognito tab (when not even logged in), if this is caching on my end it's not the browser.

Comment: On what page is that? Your link gives a Page Not Found error for me.

Comment: I also just saw this. A question listed as "Asked 12 minutes ago", despite it being deleted 4 days ago. I browsed with [this filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=30). If this is caching, then it's a somewhat broken cache.

Comment: Doing a force refresh of the page, rather than just using my bookmark, seemed to change the older content. Smells of a bug in the JavaScript used for refreshing.

Comment: CTRL + F5 :) ...

Comment: No spoilers, please.