# "Asked 4 minutes ago" on listing but question itself shows it was asked much earlier

Tags: bug, questions, time

When I'm on the question listing while filtering by a specific tag, I sometimes see questions that are supposed to have been asked a few minutes ago, as per the screenshot:

[image]

But when I go onto the question, it shows that it was asked much earlier than that:

[image]

I don't get if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. It doesn't happen *everytime* and I couldn't tell what it is triggered by.

Has anyone experimented this bug?

- Chrome 45
- Windows 7

Feel free to ask for more info.

Comment: www.shouldiblamecaching.org ?

Comment: You may be right, but this is quite annoying as I'm mostly looking for newly asked questions.

Comment: Oh I get that :P I'm not saying it's annoying or not. Just saying it's probably due to some caching somewhere... although there is quite a huge difference between "4 minutes" and "close to 2 weeks"... so if it IS caching, it would be slightly concerning

Comment: @Patrice: I couldn't agree more. There's quite a gap between those two dates.

Comment: If you're on the [new nav, there's this bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300357/4320665) which might be related.  Somehow the browser back button loads a really stale view of the page.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Yes, I'm on the new nav so it's reassuring to know I'm not the only who has experimented this bug. Do you mean each time I browse back to the question listing, I should manually refresh the page?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Yes, refreshing the page seems to do the trick. I've therefore closed this question as a duplicate.