# New homepage navigation breaks forward button

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

In the spirit of ‹[New homepage navigation breaks back button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300233/1968)›, the *newly* new homepage now breaks the forward button, and this bug was introduced very recently. To reproduce:

- Using Chrome 46.0.2490.71 on OS X 10.10
- Go to https://stackoverflow.com/
- Click on a question
- Go “back” in the browser history navigation
- Try to go “forward” again.

Result:

You cannot go forward, and the “forward” button is greyed out.

Comment: same here - using Chrome 46.0.2490.86 / Win 7 Pro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3920` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3025` (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: That was fast — not so much the fix, but the deployment. Kudos!