# Backwards navigation not maintained when using pages

Tags: bug, status-deferred, new-nav

**Edit:** My question appears to be a partial duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300233/new-homepage-navigation-breaks-back-button?rq=1) though mine is particularly about the paging aspect. However that question has been marked `status-completed` which since I can still repro this issue I don't think is accurate.

When navigating to a question on a page other than the first the back button will return me to the first page, which is quite frustrating if you're actively trying to work through the list.

Steps to repro:

- Navigate to any question list
- Click next page - now on page 2
- Click next page - now on page 3
- Click any question
- Click browser back button

Expected result - browser navigates back to page 3

Actual result - browser navigates back to page 1

This can be avoided by opening questions in new tabs rather than clicking the question but I don't think it is ideal.

This is using the new navigation system.

Comment: *This is using the new navigation system.* You hipster ;) This doesn't happen with the Old Navigation System, which partially explains why some of us are sticking to the Old Navigation System.

Comment: Well to quote one Barney Stintson - "New is always better" :)

Comment: So, you have a question list.  You are clicking on next page, next page, next page, so are now on page 4 of the question list.  Then you click the browser "back", and instead of reaching page 3 you are instead sent to page 1?  Or, you click on next page, next page, next page.  Then you click on a question. Then you click on browser-back, and end up on page 1 instead of page 4 of the question list?

Comment: @Yakk The second scenario is the one I'm reporting, the first seems to work fine.

Comment: @miken32, nice find, interesting that mine has been updated by SO (status-deferred) but that one has not.