# Filter caching not updating

Tags: support, bug, filtering

Fairly new as a professional developer so I'm not sure my terminology is correct, but I've discovered a bug in the new custom filters feature.  I've created a simple  filter for tags that I feel comfortable giving answers in and noticed that the results seem to cache incorrectly.  For example, currently the results from my filter look like this after clicking the filter from the "Saved Filters" sidebar:

[image: current]

What I've noticed however, is that upon clicking into a question and hitting the back button, the results are completely different, older questions.
[image: after back]

After looking at the results a little more, you'll notice that each of these results is actually from May 10th and earlier -- yet the time and view counts are completely wrong after updating the filter results. In fact, these old results seem to be shown from the time I enabled custom filtering.
[image]

In summary, seems to be a bug in the new feature that should be addressed.

EDIT:  Upon further investigation, it seems that these old results are stored from the time the filter was saved as any new filters produce the correct result.  I've now added an additional filter using the same tags plus one related tag and that filter brings up the correct results when hitting back from a clicked question.

Additionally, using the first filter, clicking into a question, and clicking back removes the new saved filter from the "Saved Filters" sidebar.

Comment: Using the back button on SO has never worked properly. That is not introduced due to custom filters. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300233/new-homepage-navigation-breaks-back-button

Comment: @rene While that may be true, clicking a Watched Tag, clicking into a question, and clicking back does work as expected.  Seems to me like the developers could simply duplicate the same behavior from another type of tag search.  Additionally, that link shows a `status-completed` tag indicating that was addressed, does it not?

Comment: @rene In fact, I can't reproduce the behavior described in that link whatsoever, nor is the time frame remotely similar.  The answer in your link refers to a difference of about an hour.  This is a three day difference AND the timestamp and view counts are from three days prior.  The answer in the link does not have this issue.